# Why is the result different for a tiny change regarding abstract trait member val initialization?

Tags: scala

I got the following code snippet referring an example in Chapter 6 of "Programming Scala":

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    trait AbstractT2 {
      println("In AbstractT2:")
      val value: Int
      val inverse = 1.0 / value // ???
      println("AbstractT2: value = " + value + ", inverse = " + inverse)
    }

    val c2b = new AbstractT2 {
      println("In c2b:")   //---->line 1
      val value = 10       //---->line 2
    }
    println("c2b.value = " + c2b.value + ", inverse = " + c2b.inverse)
  }
}
```

The result of the above code is:

```
In AbstractT2:
AbstractT2: value = 0, inverse = Infinity
In c2b:
c2b.value = 10, inverse = Infinity
```

Since the anonymous class initialization is after the trait initialization, the result is understandable. But if I exchange line 1 and line 2 in the above example, so that `val value = 10` precedes `println("In c2b:")`, the result will be:

```
In AbstractT2:
AbstractT2: value = 10, inverse = 0.1
In c2b:
c2b.value = 10, inverse = 0.1
```

It seems this time the initialization is successful although it's wrong from language point of view. I can't understand why. Can anybody help on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmmm.... verified against Scala 2.8.0.final, and see the same results in the both cases: In AbstractT2: 
AbstractT2: value = 0, inverse = Infinity In c2b:
c2b.value = 10, inverse = Infinity

Comment: I can confirm Vasil's comment. Same here with Scala 2.8.0.final. What version do you use?

Comment: The version I used to get the above result is 2.7.7.final. I tested this against 2.8.0 just now, and the results for both cases are correct as you said. So it seems to be a bug of 2.7.7 or 2.7.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to 2.7 Scala moved value initializations in front of the superclass constructor
until an initialization which references `this` was encountered. There it would stop.
Much, much earlier, this behavior was necessary to get some composition patterns working. Later, we introduced early definitions to get the same patterns working in a more robust way.
But since the behavior was difficult to change it took us until 2.8 to actually do it.

Answer (score 5):

Initialization semantics changed from 2.7 to 2.8.  Here's the commit, way back in 2008.  "HARD HATS ON!"

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/16745

Comment: Hi, do you mean the current behavior in 2.7 is also correct as designed? Thanks.

Comment: I mean that the behavior you are demonstrating is the expected behavior in 2.7.  "Correct" is a more ambitious claim with I can neither confirm nor deny, but the point is moot unless you would like to start maintaining the 2.7 branch.